How to fix the Fill color remove the graphs under it using ApexChart.js
I'm using a method because I'm looping through datasets from an API. 1 key have multiple different lines
  generateRainbowColor(index) {
    const hue = (index * 360 / this.list.length) % 360;
    return `hsl(${hue}, 100%, 50%)`;
  },
    generateFill() {
      const baseColors = ["#FFFFFF", "#94ddf7", "#94ddf7", "#FFFFFF", "#94ddf7", "#FFFFFF"];
      const baseOpacity = [0, 0, 0.5, 1, 0.2, 1];
      const fillColors = [];
      const fillOpacity = [];
      const stops = [0, 50, 100];

      for (let i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < baseColors.length; j++) {
          fillColors.push(baseColors[j]);
          fillOpacity.push(baseOpacity[j]);
        }
      }

      return {
        colors: fillColors,
        opacity: fillOpacity,
        type: "solid",
        stops: stops,
      };
    },
    generateStroke() {
    const baseWidth = [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1];
    const strokeColors = [];
    const strokeWidth = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
      const color = this.generateRainbowColor(i);
      for (let j = 0; j < baseWidth.length; j++) {
        strokeColors.push(color);
        strokeWidth.push(baseWidth[j]);
      }
    }

    return {
      show: true,
      colors: strokeColors,
      width: strokeWidth
    };
  },

Graph Image using ApexChart.js
Target Graph
As you can see, there supposed to be a line of graphs under it. but it blocked the lines because of the opacity of color white. how do I fix this?
I have tried to adjust the opacity and change the colors but nothing seems to be working. Is there any other way to fix this problem by adjusting the opacity or anything?
